# batch file segregate by filename mmdd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

so I have this idea of segregating our files by date. we have this files named as Zxxx followed by mmdd where x are numbers
and mmdd is month and date.
my initial thought is to segregate it one by one

```
@echo off 
cd C:\folder

set /p var="Enter mmdd: "

md %var%

copy c:\folder\*%var%.txt c:\folder\%var%

exit
```

Now my question is ... is there a way that it will just automatically create folders and move files with same mmdd on the
created mmdd folder. Kinda like user click batch file then computer saw 5 items that is 1208 mmdd and 3 1209 mmdd. it
 creates 1208 folder and 1209 folder and put files in there respectively.

EDIT: So it tried using for loop and exist

```
 @echo off

FOR /L %%x IN (101,1,931) DO ( IF EXIST "????0%%x.txt" MKDIR 0%%x )
FOR /L %%x IN (101,1,931) DO ( IF EXIST "????0%%x.txt" MOVE "????0%%x.txt" \0%%x\ )
FOR /L %%x IN (1001,1,1231) DO ( IF EXIST "????%%x.txt" MKDIR 0%%x )
FOR /L %%x IN (1001,1,1231) DO ( IF EXIST "????%%x.txt" MOVE "????0%%x.txt" \0%%x\ )
pause
```

but it having an error "Cannot move multiple files to a single file."

I

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring of the date-variable for this.

```
Syntax:
      %variable:~num_chars_to_skip%
      %variable:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%
```

[Taken from SS64.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

This is how it works to extract year, month and day:

```
set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~-7,2%
set day=%date:~-10,2%
```

You can now reference these, e.g. by using `mkdir C:\folder\%year%\%month%-%day%` to create a structure like `C:\folder\2017\01-25\`.

If you need more powerful features for date handling, please consider moving to powershell.

Comment: Hi.if I were to use a substring how can i do it like for every zxxx1208 it creates 1208 folder and put it there then for every 1209 folder it creates folder and put it there until all files are segregated loop

Comment: Using the technique I described above. You loop over all the files in the source directory, get the substring of the file that is currently in the loop and write it to a variable every loop. You can then use that variable to move the file to the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D C:\folder
For %%A in (z*.txt) Do Echo:%%A|Findstr /i "^z[0-9][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9].txt$" >NUL 2>&1 &&(
  Set Filename=%%A
  Set MMDD=!Filename:~3,4!
  If Not Exist !MMDD! MD !MMDD!
  Move %%A !MMDD!
)
```

- The for iterates over the the matching files
- Echo:%%A|Findstr... validates the 7 number pattern coarsely verifying MM/DD
- The use of `!` instead of `%` for the vars is necassary because this is inside a (code block) requiring delayed expansion.
- `!Filename:~3,4!` is a substring expression extracting from zero based 4th position 4 numbers.